# DOJO: Dynamic creation/Loading/fetching of trees

Tags: html, ajax

I want to load a tree structure in dojo dynamically with every layer loading(fetching data from server) only after a click to the next layer is made. This would help me to not have the entire tree loaded in memory all together but as someone clicks a level of a tree, only then all the elements of the next level are fetched from the server using ajax requests in dojo.
Can someone help me on how to go about this?

Comment: The answer for this is here as follows: using a dijit tree, it has just 3 steps to create a dynamic tree that loads lazily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for this is here as follows: using a dijit tree, it has just 3 steps to create a dynamic tree that loads lazily: 1. Create a store, 2. Create a model, 3. Create the tree. Here is the code snippet that I used which worked perfectly:

```
function createLazyTreeStore()
{
    var store = new JsonRest({
        target: "location where your file is",

            getChildren: function(object) {
                // object may just be stub object, so get the full object first and then return it's
                // list of children
                return this.get(object.id).then(function(fullObject){
                    console.log(fullObject.children);
                    return fullObject.children;
                });
            }
        });
    return store;
}
function createModel(store)
{
    var model = new ObjectStoreModel({
        store: store,
        getRoot: function(onItem) {
            this.store.get("the .php file").then(function(item)
            {
                onItem(item[0]);
            });
        },

        getChildren: function(object, onComplete, onError)
        {
            this.store.get("your url to fetch the data with parent child relation").then(function(fullObject) {
            object.children = fullObject;
            onComplete(object.children);
            }, function(error)
            {
                console.error(error);
                onComplete([]);
            });
        },
        mayHaveChildren: function(object) {

            return true;
        }
    });
    return model;
}
function createTree(model)
{
    var tree = new Tree({
        model: model,
        style: "your preference",
        id: "tree",
    });
    return tree;
}

Then call these functions in the following order:
var store = createLazyTreeStore();
var model = createModel(store);
var tree = createTree(model);
accordionPane.addChild(tree);
```